# Access to class inside Union

Tags: c++, namespaces, unions

I have the declaration of class `A`inside a third party library, so I can't modify it.
I need to use the declaration of class `B` to pass it to a method, **is there a way to do it without modifying class `A`?**

When I try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    union {
        class B
        {
            public:
            int x;
        };
    }un;
};

void foo(A::B & test)
{
}

int main() {
    A::B test;
    test.x=10;
    cout << test.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error:

> error: `B` is not a member of `A`

[Live Example!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f748011b33948e13)

My assumption is that it happens because `B` is in a unnamed namespace.

PS: If I could modify the declaration of the `union`
from:

```
union {...
```

to:

```
union T {...
```

This will be done simple by:

```
A::T::B test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type of the union using `decltype`, then you can access `B`:

```
decltype(std::declval<A&>().un)::B test;
```

[**coliru example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06e8d29551afa487)

Comment: Wow! that was fast! Thanks, btw I wonder if this can be done also for c++03